# How do I size a Firefox Add-on SDK popup/panel? Firefox Add-on SDK popup/panel too small

Tags: css, popup, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I followed the [tutorial on creating a popup for an add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Display_a_Popup) in Firefox, and it worked great.

The issue I'm having now is that the popup it creates doesn't change size to fit the content I add to it.  Instead, it adds scroll bars.

So, how do I change the size of a Firefox Add-on SDK popup to show all content?

Comment: If you are asking about how to have the panel *automatically* size to fit your content, then please clarify your question. If you are looking for how to specify the `height` and `width` of the panel, then you should have found this in the [documentation for the `panel()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Panel%28options%29). Those properties are the first two listed. When you have questions, reading the base documentation for the methods you are using should be one of the first things you do. The panel doc page is the first link in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have to deal with that yourself.

If you already know the desired size when creating the panel, you can pass the `height` and `width` as properties of the object to the `Panel()` constructor.

After a panel is created, its size can be changed by setting the `height` and `width` properties on it.

`height` and `width` values are numbers in pixels.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel for a full documentation of how to use panels.

Answer (score 1):

Though the tutorial and docs never say it, the height and width of a panel always defaults to the same small size.

To change it you can use the [height and width parameters for the panel class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Parameters).

If you want it to change automatically you can use this code:

```
//index.js
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    height: 200,  //choose your default
    width: 200,
    contentURL: data.url("popup.html"),
    contentScriptFile: data.url("auto_resize_popup.js")
});

panel.port.on("resize", function (size) {
    console.log(size);
    panel.resize(size.width, size.height);
});
```

...

```
//auto_resize_popup.js

    var content = document.body;
    var size = {};
    size.width = content.offsetWidth + 2;  //2 extra pixels get rid of scroll bars
    size.height = content.offsetHeight + 2;
    self.port.emit("resize", size);
```